# Any software to make Win8+ interface look alike Win7?

Tags: windows-8, gui

i.e. it should add shadows to buttons and windows, make scrollbars and panels beveled as they were pre-Win8, etc.

I'm not asking for transformation of Start Menu.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Classic Shell](http://sourceforge.net/projects/classicshell/)- **Start menu and Windows enhancement software**

Features

- Classic Start Menu for Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8 (with
  skins)
- Toolbar for Windows Explorer
- Classic copy UI (Vista and Windows 7 only)
- Show file size in Explorer status bar (Vista and Windows 7 only)
- Title bar and status bar for Internet Explorer (9 and up)

Download Link /Source http://sourceforge.net/projects/classicshell/